# why is chrome failing to load my custom extension with error "Service worker registration failed. Status code: 10"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I am trying to load my custom extension in chrome, but I'm getting an error and the service worker is marked as "inactive"

[image]

This is my manifest file contents (removed sensitive paths):

```
{
    "name": "Quicker",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Automation quick actions performer",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "background",
        "management"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "..."
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
                "contentScript.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "..."
            ],
            "css": [
                "jenkinsStyle.css"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "..."
            ],
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "icons": {
        "128": "autoCog.png"
    }
}
```

I've tried resetting chrome, updating, reinstalling. I've also tried to load the background file in a try/catch block and to load an empty background file all attempts yield the above state.

Comment: Remove the extension before reinstalling it. Also make sure the file background.js is in the same directory as manifest.json, not inside a sub-directory.

Comment: thanks for your comment @wOxxOm i tried reinstalling, and the background.js is in the same directory as manifest.json ... did not help

Comment: Not simply reinstalling, but you need to remove the extension first.

Comment: i also tried that ... no change

Comment: There's no problem with your manifest.json, so either there is a bug in Chrome or there's something in your background.js.

Comment: Is this question in any way related to [Quicker Connector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quicker-connector/klggbkjfmbonefdcfkiidhcmfjdfnepa)?

Comment: "quicker" is a custom extension that i created - no connection to "Quicker Connector"

Comment: Error #10 is `// Operation is failed by network issue.
  kErrorNetwork = 10,
`
In the ServiceWorker registration, are there any network calls to cache resources that would be returning a non-200 response, or a response with a cert error? Are there any redirects?

Comment: Thanks @EricLaw for your update, no i dont have errornous calls or redirects. found a strange workaround for this issue for chrome: go to Settings -> System -> toggle "Use hardware acceleration when available" restart the browser and toggle again. for some reason my custom extension works fine after that

Comment: That setting absolutely should have no impact, unless your GPU driver is crashing one of the processes that Chromium is using.

Comment: I have the same issue. When I click "reload" button, it shows me an error, "Manifest file is missing or unreadable" and a path to my extension in the /private/var directory. If I go there, indeed there is nothing but empty folders. Are files are gone. It happens only after closing my MacBook for a few hours and opening it again. And not always, just sometimes. Seems like browser/os related issue.